# Error on facebook logout in android app

Tags: android

In my `android` application, using facebook account I can login to my app, but when i am trying to logout from facebook (from application), showing error.

Here is my code.

```
mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // make Login button visible


                    }

                });

            }
        }
```

Error

> 11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-98
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:86)
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.facebook.Utility.clearCookiesForDomain(Utility.java:370)
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.facebook.Utility.clearFacebookCookies(Utility.java:394)
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.facebook.Session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(Session.java:673)
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:652)
>   11-15 06:58:22.480: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$1.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:86)

In `Utility.java` this is to work around a bug where CookieManager may fail to instantiate if `CookieSyncManager` has never been created.

```
CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
```

Please suggest any solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error in an old application that is still using the now deprecated logout method used in this question. I opted to patch the SDK for a quick fix instead of upgrading, for lack of time.

As the stack trace suggests, the problem is that at this line, the context argument passed to CookieSyncManager is null:

android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:86)

If you go further up the stack, you can see that the Context argument passed in is the staticContext member variable of the Session class in the Facebook SDK. For whatever reason, they are setting this variable to null, and thus when logout is called, the app crashes with this exception.

To fix this, I just edited the Session class to make initializeStaticContext a public method. Then, just call that before you call logout:

```
Session.initializeStaticContext(this.getApplicationContext());
mAsyncRunner.logout(...
```

Certainly, this is not the best solution, but it gets the job done.